# Azure Hybrid Connection - A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure

I am getting the following error

> [SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level error has occurred when
>   receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error:
>   19 - Physical connection is not usable)]

I have an ASP.net MVC website hosted in Azure
The database is on-premises and connected using Azure Hybrid Connection

The error occurs intermittently, a simple refresh sorts it out and then will happen again at some point.

I also have a copy of the database on another server which a test version in Azure also points to, i get the same problem, IIS is also hosted on this machine with that site internally but I have not seen any problems with that.

SQL Server Express 64 Bit 12.0.nnnn

Comment: I believe you are keeping the connection idle for so much time and trying to reconnect on same connection

Comment: Doesnt quite add up, and ill add that the reason is that if i am bulk adding a batch of new records it will work fine then on a post create will throw the error.  the record will actually have been added so it seem that it couldn't refresh the list of records on postback.

Comment: Have you managed to solve the problem?

Comment: Still not sorted unfortunatley, my gut feeling is that it is either internal network blips or SQL configuration as opposed to an issue on the Azure side or the Hybrid Service