# MVC and using DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

At the moment my convention (as i have been brought up with) of the use of the DbContext in my MVC application is as follows

I have a Base Controller Class, which all my controllers inherit

This has a class property as follows

```
public class TjiControllerBase : Controller
{
    protected TjiContext Context;

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        Context = new TjiContext();
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }


    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        Context.Dispose();
        Context = null; //Probably not needed
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
```

I have a current issue, in the Azure environment where the connection is crashing "[Transport Level Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40840356/azure-hybrid-connection-a-transport-level-error-has-occurred-when-receiving-re?noredirect=1#comment68898327_40840356)" and want to consider the above as part of this.

Should I be using, the using clause in my code instead?
Will change to [usings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj729737(v=vs.113).aspx) assist this?

Comment: I'd be using an IoC container for that sort of thing. Also, having the `DbContext` in your MVC controller suggests that the application (unless it is a quick throw away thing) is not architected properly. I'd expect the database stuff to be kept well away from MVC altogether.

Comment: @ColinMackay So, considering a well made web app, Entity is totally useless for you ?

Comment: Just use the using clause like you considered, never instantiate a context and let it open like in your code. When a function needs database info, the using clause INSIDE that function will insure that your context object is garbage collected at the end of the function. Its also more coherent for the rest of your app

Comment: @AntoinePelletiern No, EF is not totally useless to me. I just wouldn't have it any where near the MVC components of the application. In a well designed MVC web application, the controller should know nothing about your database or how you access it.